# Authors are not found for citation by natbib

Tags: bibliographies, citing, natbib

I am trying to use `Natbib` to print *et al.* for authors, for instance "Jeannet *et al.* [1]".

```
\documentclass[runningheads,orivec]{llncs}
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}
\cite{jeannetmine09}    % gives [1]
\citet{jeannetmine09}   % gives (author?) [1]
\citep{jeannetmine09}   % gives [1]
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{bibfile}
\end{document}
```

where `bibfile.bib` contains

```
@InProceedings{jeannetmine09, 
   Author = {Jeannet, B. and Min\'e, A.},
   Title = {{APRON}: A Library of Numerical Abstract Domains for Static Analysis},
   BookTitle = {Computer Aided Verification, CAV'2009},
   Volume = {5643},
   Pages = {661--667},
   Series = {LNCS},
   Year = {2009}
}
```

I don't know why `\citet{jeannetmine09}` can't find the authors as [this link](http://merkel.zoneo.net/Latex/natbib.php) shows. Could anyone help?

Comment: Use `plainnat` as bibliography style.

Comment: `\bibliographystyle{plainnat}` and `\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}`

Comment: Your example bib entry has exactly two authors. However, the author-year citation method `FirstAuthor et al` is usually applied when there are *three or more* authors. (The plainnat.bst file follows this practice.) By the way: "et al" (short for "et alii" in this case) literally translates to *and others* -- note the plural form of "others". When there are exactly two authors, there's normally little gain to be achieved by replacing "and SecondAuthor" with "et al", right?

Comment: I recently had this same issue, but was unable to use an author-year style, as the journal required their own numeric `bst` file. I provide the workaround I used, in [another answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/581542/134641).

Answer (score 8):

I answered in the comment you should use the bibliography style `plainnat`.

In combination with this bibliography style you have to submit the option `numbers` to `natbib`.

Here the complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{bibfile.bib}
@InProceedings{jeannetmine09, 
   Author = {Jeannet, B. and Min\'e, A.},
   Title = {{APRON}: A Library of Numerical Abstract Domains for Static Analysis},
   BookTitle = {Computer Aided Verification, CAV'2009},
   Volume = {5643},
   Pages = {661--667},
   Series = {LNCS},
   Year = {2009}
} 

\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\cite{jeannetmine09}    % gives [1]

\citet{jeannetmine09}   % gives (author?) [1]

\citep{jeannetmine09}   % gives [1]

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{bibfile}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

PS: Please don't provide examples with unknown (i.e. not on CTAN) document classes unless (i) the class is relevant to the problem you're having and (ii) you supply a link to the class.

Comment: Did you mean to suggest the use of the option `authoryear`, rather than `numbers`? The `numbers` option simply instructs `natbib` to use a *numeric* citation style when instructions such as `\cite` and `\citep` are encountered.