# Author cite miss in own bst file

Tags: natbib

I created my own `cmu2014.bst` by `makebst`. I am able to cite articles, via `\citep`, except `\citeauthor` and `\citet` do not work as anticipated. They instead show **(author?)**.

This is part of my TeX file

```
\usepackage[sort,compress,numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{./bst/cmu2014}
\bibliography{./bib/Ref}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a solution for that. I had to address this very same problem some days ago. The solution is given in http://osl.ugr.es/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/natbib/natbib.pdf, Sections 2.4 and 3.

First of all, you need to create the `.bst` file (with `makebst`) as an *author-year* reference style. This is important. So maybe you'll have to run `makebst` again.

Then, as far as I remember, you don't have to change anything in your `.tex` code, that is:

```
\usepackage[sort,compress,numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{./bst/cmu2014}  % created as author-year
\bibliography{./bib/Ref}
```

Just make sure to compile the code several times, as usual when you change things related to bibliography.

If this doesn’t work for you, try to add

```
\setcitestyle{numbers}
```

after including `natbib`, but this would be redundant.

Please, let me know if this worked for you.

EDIT: I changed the reference to the `natbib`documentation, thanks to @Mico. To be more precise, it is in section 2.4 where I got the information. Regarding `\citeauthor` and other similar commands, there it clearly says:

> Note: these commands may also be used with numerical citations, provided an author-year `.bst`file is being employed.

I had the same problem as @BonSai. The problem that @BonSai has is that he is trying to get author information from a `.bst` file that was created as a *number* reference style.
If you create a `.bst` file as an *author-year* style (and only then), it is possible to get correct results when you use things like `\citeauthor` even when you use `natbib` with the `numbers` option. And this is also related to the Section 3 of the documentation, which specifies how you can use *author-year* reference styles with *number* citation styles.

EDIT: As @Mico pointed out, this answer wouldn't solve the problem with `\citet` that the Post Owner (PO; @BonSai) reported. Nevertheless, I still think that the problem is related with the `.bst` file. It has to be created again as an *author-year* reference style.

Anyway, a MWE would be desirable on the part of the PO, of course.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't told us which options you passed to the `makebst` utility when you created your own bibliography style file. Based on the bits of information you've provided, though, I suspect you told `makebst` that you want numerical-style citation callouts (which is the utility's default style). To wit, consider the following output, generated with the `plain` bibliography style, which is known *not* to be compatible with authoryear-style callouts. Observe that `\citep` and `\cite` produce a number in brackets, whereas `\citet` and `\citeauthor` produce "**(author?)**".

[image]

This problem does *not* occur if the code is re-run with the style set to, say, `plainnat` or `apalike` -- both of which can produce both authoryear-style and numeric-style citation callouts. The remedy, then, is to make sure that `makebst` is rerun with a suitable `authoryear`-style callout system.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{abc,
   author = "Anne Author",
   title  = "Thoughts",
   journal= "Circularity Today",
   year   = 3001,
}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib} 
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\begin{document}
\cite{abc}, \citep{abc}

\citet{abc}, \citeauthor{abc}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this same issue, but was unable to use an author-year style, as the journal required their own numeric `bst` file.

Accordingly, I used the below workaround, to allow me to use simple `\citet` commands. I hope this might prove useful to others in this situation.

```
\usepackage{xifthen}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{usebib}


\newbibfield{author} % allow manual retrieval of "author" field; must precede \bibinput


\newcounter{numAuthors}

% N.B. only accepts a single reference.
\renewrobustcmd{\citet}[1]{%
    \edef\expAuthors{\usebibentry{#1}{author}}%
    %
    \setcounter{numAuthors}{1}% % reset and start from 1
    %
    \def\numAuthorsInt{}%
    \StrCount{\expAuthors}{and}[\numAuthorsInt]%
    \addtocounter{numAuthors}{\numAuthorsInt}%
    %
    \ifthenelse{\value{numAuthors} = 1}{%
        % a single author
        \StrBefore{\expAuthors}{,}~\cite{#1}%
    }%
    {\ifthenelse{\value{numAuthors} = 2}{%
        % two authors
        \def\secondAuthInt{}%
        \StrBehind{\expAuthors}{and}[\secondAuthInt]%
        %
        \StrBefore{\expAuthors}{,}~and \StrBefore{\secondAuthInt}{,}~\cite{#1}%
    }{%
        % more than 2 authors
        \StrBefore{\expAuthors}{,}~et~al.\@{}~\cite{#1}%
    }}%
}
```